# Hardware support for non-power-of-two textures

Tags: opengl, graphics, textures

I have been hearing controversial opinions on whether it is safe to use non-power-of two textures in OpenGL applications. Some say all modern hardware supports NPOT textures perfectly, others say it doesn't or there is a big performance hit.

The reason I'm asking is because I want to render something to a frame buffer the size of the screen (which may not be a power of two) and use it as a texture. I want to understand what is going to happen to performance and portability in this case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Arbitrary texture sizes have been specified as core part of OpenGL ever since OpenGL-2, which was a long time ago (2004). All GPUs designed every since do support NP2 textures just fine. The only question is how good the performance is.

However ever since GPUs got programmable any optimization based on the predictable patterns of fixed function texture gather access became sort of obsolete and GPUs now have caches optimized for general data locality and performance is not much of an issue now either. In fact, with P2 textures you may need to upscale the data to match the format, which increases the required memory bandwidth. However memory bandwidth is the #1 bottleneck of modern GPUs. So using a slightly smaller NP2 texture may actually improve performance.

In short: You can use NP2 textures safely and performance is not much of a big issue either.

Comment: Thanks, and i was foolish enough to use old opengl version and struggling with the power of 2 graphics till 2014, thanks for confirming i will use OpenGl 2.0 from now on and will deal with Non power of 2 graphics, i am so happy and dum on the other side, lol.

Answer (score 3):

All modern APIs (except some versions of OpenGL ES, I believe) on modern graphics hardware (the last 10 or so generations from ATi/AMD/nVidia and the last couple from Intel) support NP2 texture just fine. They've been in use, particularly for post-processing, for quite some time.

However, that's not to say they're as convenient as power-of-2 textures. One major case is memory packing; drivers can often pack textures into memory far better when they are powers of two. If you look at a texture with mipmaps, the base and all mips can  be packed into an area 150% the original width and 100% the original height. It's also possible that certain texture sizes will line up memory pages with stride (texture row size, in bytes), which would provide an optimal memory access situation. NP2 makes this sort of optimization harder to perform, and so memory usage and addressing may be a hair less efficient. Whether you'll notice any effect is very much driver and application-dependent.

Offscreen effects are perhaps the most common usecase for NP2 textures, especially screen-sized textures. Almost every game on the market now that performs any kind of post-processing or deferred rendering has 1-15 offscreen buffers, many of which are the same size as the screen (for some effects, half or quarter-size are useful). These are generally well-supported, even with mipmaps.

Because NP2 textures are widely supported and almost a sure bet on desktops and consoles, using them should work just fine. If you're worried about platforms or hardware where they may not be supported, easy fallbacks include using the nearest power-of-2 size (may cause slightly lower quality, but will work) or dropping the effect entirely (with obvious consquences).

Answer (score 2):

I have a lot of experience in making games (+4 years) and using texture atlases for iOS & Android though cross platform development using OpenGL 2.0

Stick with PoT textures with a maximum size of 2048x2048 because some devices (especially the cheap ones with cheap hardware) still don't support dynamic texture sizes, i know this from real life testers and seeing it first hand. There are so many devices out there now, you never know what sort of GPU you'll be facing.

You're iOS devices will also show black squares and artefacts if you are not using PoT textures.

Just a tip.

Answer (score 1):

Even if arbitrary texture size is required by OpenGL X certain videocards are still not fully compliant with OpenGL. I had a friend with a IntelCard having problems with NPOT2 textures (I assume now Intel Cards are fully compliant).

Do you have any reason for using NPOT2 Textures? than do it, but remember that maybe some old hardware don't support them and you'll probably need some software fallback that can make your textures POT2.

Don't you have any reason for using NPOT2 Textures? then just use POT2 Textures. (certain compressed formats still requires POT2 textures)